# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1890 column 29 (char 83535)

Tags: python, json

I have this json file https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjza7cu136ye06e/configClear_v2.json?dl=0

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_02.py", line 8, in <module>
    data.append(json.load(f))
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1890 column 29 (char 83535)
```

test_02.py

```
import json
with open("configClear_v2.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(data)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. If you don't know how to debug this, figuring out how to examine what's in the input file at line 1890 should not be hard to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is invalid. The lines leading up to 1890 are this:

```
                                {
                                    "sequence": 90,
                                    "ace-rule": {
                                        "action": "deny",
                                        "protocol": "ip",
                                        "dst-host": "217.105.224.25",
                                        "any": [
                                            null
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                         
                            ]
                        },
```

1890 is the last `]`. The error is `},` 2 lines before. You can't have a `,` after the last element of an array or object in JSON. This is allowed in a number of programming languages (Python, PHP, JavaScript, for example), but JSON is deliberately more restrictive in its syntax, since it's not intended for humans to write by hand.

Remove the `,` after the `}` and the error will go away. Then fix whatever program is creating the JSON. You should always use a library function to create JSON, to ensure that it's properly formatted.